# adding 'rows' to dictionary in a WHILE loop

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I am missing something small here and could use a pointer.  I am trying to generate data to save time for my work with CRUD work in a database via `pymonogo` and other pythonic database libraries.  Below is the code that I am having trouble with.  I would like to create a function which creates a dictionary of length `n` but I cannot figure out how to append the dictionary appropriately.  As you can see, it only enters in the last item of the list generated.  Any input would be great!

```rb
import names
import random
import numpy as np

age_choices = np.arange(18, 90)
gender_choices = ['male', 'female']
salary_choices = np.arange(10000, 200000)

def create_data(n=20):
    age_choices = np.arange(18, 90)
    gender_choices = ['male', 'female']
    salary_choices = np.arange(10000, 200000)
    
    person_values = []
    data_dict = {}
    
    unique_id = 0
    
    while unique_id < n:
        age = random.choice(age_choices)
        gender = random.choice(gender_choices)
        salary = random.choice(salary_choices)
        person_keys = ['id', 'name', 'gender', 'age', 'salary']
        person_values = [unique_id, names.get_full_name(gender), gender, age, salary]
    
        for k, v in zip(person_keys, person_values):
            data_dict[k] = v
            
        unique_id += 1
       
    return person_values, data_dict

data_list, data_dict = create_data(5)
print(data_list)
print()
print(data_dict)
```

current outputs:

```rb
[4, 'Anthony Shultz', 'male', 29, 188503] # This is the last item of the list generated in the while loop

{'id': 4, 'name': 'Anthony Shultz', 'gender': 'male', 'age': 29, 'salary': 188503} # This is the "whole" dictionary generated but should have length 5 since n=5
```

**The desired out put should be a dictionary of length `n` not just one**.

Comment: Dictionaries don't have "length" and you cannot "append" to dictionary. Do you mean you want a list of dictionaries as an output?

Comment: yes, I would like 5 items to be output

Comment: since n = 5, the term "length" was probably not semantically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should introduce another variable in your function which would be a list or tuple and append each `data_dict` to it, every time you create one. You should also create a unique `data_dict` in your `while` loop, on every iteration. For example (check the lines with comments):

```
import names
import random
import numpy as np

age_choices = np.arange(18, 90)
gender_choices = ['male', 'female']
salary_choices = np.arange(10000, 200000)


def create_data(n=20):
    age_choices = np.arange(18, 90)
    gender_choices = ['male', 'female']
    salary_choices = np.arange(10000, 200000)

    person_values = []
    all_data = []  # Make a list which will store all our dictionaries

    unique_id = 0

    while unique_id < n:
        data_dict = {}  # Create a dictionary with current values
        age = random.choice(age_choices)
        gender = random.choice(gender_choices)
        salary = random.choice(salary_choices)
        person_keys = ['id', 'name', 'gender', 'age', 'salary']
        person_values = [unique_id, names.get_full_name(gender), gender, age,
                         salary]

        for k, v in zip(person_keys, person_values):
            data_dict[k] = v

        all_data.append(data_dict)  # Add newly created `data_dict` dictionary to our list
        unique_id += 1

    return person_values, data_dict, all_data  # Return as desired


data_list, data_dict, all_data = create_data(5)  # Just as an example
print(data_list)
print()
print(data_dict)
print()
print(all_data)  # Print the output
```

This will result in list of dictionaries, which I assume you want as an output, e.g.:

```
[{'id': 0, 'name': 'David Medina', 'gender': 'male', 'age': 87, 'salary': 67957}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Valentina Reese', 'gender': 'female', 'age': 68, 'salary': 132938}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Laura Franklin', 'gender': 'female', 'age': 84, 'salary': 93839}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Melita Pierce', 'gender': 'female', 'age': 21, 'salary': 141055}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'Brenda Clay', 'gender': 'female', 'age': 36, 'salary': 94385}]
```

Comment: yup, Thank you!  I knew it was something small and I think I just stared at it for too long.  I also knew that I would need to add to a list.  Thanks for your quick and accurate response.

Comment: @TheMattdavis17 No problem, I’m glad I helped!

Comment: uh-oh, I should have looked earlier.  I'm getting the same output in the all_data dictionary.  I'll see why and respond back here as a comment.

Comment: @TheMattdavis17 I noticed the mistake too, updated my answer now!

Comment: great, thanks.  I'll check it out and get back to you.  Thanks again!

Comment: perfect, thanks!  I have a tendency to quickly accept without error checking, one of my (of many) downfalls as a developer!

Comment: I also sometimes answer too quickly before double checking the answer ^^